# import fizzbuzz not found

Tags: android, import, dagger

I have 'inherited' a source code that I should maintain. It contains import statements about fizzbuzz and dagger that fail. I never used those and am stuck now.
[image]

Here the dependencies in build.gradle:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes sync helps, give it a try if you haven't.

Comment: Also try this in build.gradle: `repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}`